# what does this syntax mean? anArray[source].src = sourceImg;

Tags: javascript, object, encapsulation

```
var source = 0;
var subtitue = 1;

function rollOver(sourceImg,  subImg) {

    var arrayImg = new Array;

    arrayImg[source] = new Image;
    arrayImg[source].src = sourceImg;
    arrayImg[subtitute] = new Image;
    arrayImg[subtitute].src = subImg;

    return arrayImg;
}
```

Comment: You can use bracket notation when accessing properties of an object in JS. Have a look at this: https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means set the value of the object at `anArray[source]` to the value of `sourceImg`.

Here `arrayImg` is an `Array`, which is normally represented as:

```
var arrayImg = [];
```

The `source` parameter is an index into that array, but because it's JavaScript, it doesn't actually need to be a number. This leads to confusion and/or issues, e.g., if `source = 1000` you now have a 1000-entry array with a lot of `undefined` values, and it's pointless.

This is fairly risky, and ultimately bad, code. It would be better expressed as an object, e.g.,

```
function rollOver(srcImg,  subImg) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = srcImg;

  var sub = new Image();
  sub.src = subImg;

  return {
     main: img,
     sub:  sub
  };
}
```

(Noting that this is still heinous, and requires the code that's using the function to be fixed to not rely on position for values, because that's brittle.)

Bottom line is that if this JS confuses you, SO is not the place to start, rather you should be looking at some basic JavaScript tutorials, and learn it right.

Answer (score 0):

`anArray` is an array.

`source` is the index into the array. JavaScript can use any value as the index.

An object of type `Image` exists and is assigned to the value at that index.

The `.src` sets an attribute of that object the value of `sourceImg`.

Now for the parameters... 
`source` is set as 0, and `sourceImage` was passed into the function.

So `arrayIndex[0]` is set to a new `Image` object, and that object has its `src` attribute set to the `sourceImage` value sent into the function.

It could have been written like this:

```
let image = new Image()
image.src = srcImage
arrayIndex[0] = image
```

Comment: I had submitted that last source and it did not 'take'.  Then i saw your comment...

Comment: Hey @DaveNewton, https://www.quora.com/Should-the-s-in-JavaScript-be-capitalized.  I learn something new every day!

Comment: Yup--and I check for that when I review candidate resumes! And if they "SmallTalk" I'm immediately suspicious. Being old and cantankerous has its downsides.

Comment: Have you ever heard how the original Java developers pronounce 'Java'?  Some things just were not meant to be.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/5qb7dc3w/5/

I use bracket notation when dynamical access to attribute of object.

```
const obj = {
  id: "user",
  password: "password"
};

Object.keys(obj)
    .forEach(function(key) {
        const val = obj[key];
    document.querySelector(`input[name="${key}"]`).value = val;
    });
```